# How do you write a program where you can enter a maximum of 5 characters in a string, but also less than 5(in Ada)?

Tags: string, max, ada, ada95

My code so far. It does not work however.
I would like to be able to write something like "go", "car" or "truck", as long as it's 5 characters or less, and the programme will then write that word out. I think i need to use Get_Line an Put_Line but i do not know how to use them.

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Ada_O1_1 is
   
   I : Integer;
   S : String(1..5);

begin
   Put("Write a string with a maximum of 5 characters: ");
   Get(S, Last =>I);
   Put("You wrote the string: ");
   Put(S(1..I));
end Ada_O1_1;
```

Comment: Try using Get_Line instead of Get. Also, your context clause needs to be fixed. Use Ada.Text_IO rather than Ada.Integer_Text_IO. I suggest you read the Ada Language Reference Manual Appendix A description of these packages so you understand how they work.

Comment: What should happen if the user tries to enter more than 5 characters?

Comment: If you add more than 5 characters only the first 5 should be printed

Answer (score 2):

Get_Line returns a varying length String result and Ada requires that String objects have a known size at instantiation.  The way around this is to initialize a String variable with the Get_Line result.  You can do this inside a declare block:

```ada
declare
   Line : String := Get_Line;
begin
   -- Do stuff here like check the length of the Line variable and
   -- adjust how your code works based on that.  Note that the Line
   -- variable goes out of scope once you leave the block (after "end")
end;
```

Inside the begin/end part of the block you can check the length of the line returned and verify that it is less than or equal to 5 and do your error handling based on that result.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in the form of a loop, which (a) makes using it slightly easier, (b) adds the need for handling empty and over-length inputs.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Ada_O1_1 is

   I : Integer;
   S : String (1 .. 5);

begin
   loop
      Put ("Write a string with a maximum of 5 characters (end with <RET>): ");
      Get_Line (S, Last => I);
      exit when I = 0;  -- i.e. an empty line
      if I = S'Last then
         --  there are still characters in the input buffer
         Skip_Line;
      end if;
      Put ("You wrote the string: ");
      Put_Line (S (1 .. I));
   end loop;
end Ada_O1_1;
```